# Determining absolute convergence

Tags: calculus

Consider the following infinite series.

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac {x^{2k-1}} {2k-1}$$

How does one determine the absolute convergence of this series? For $|x| < 1$ one can compare this with the geometric series and conclude absolute convergence, but for $|x| > 1$ I can't seem to find a suitable series to compare with. Apparently this should be solvable without requiring the ratio test.

Comment: [Ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) will answer ;-)

Comment: Is there no other way to go about it?

Comment: I edited my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

For $|x| > 1$ simply consider that $\frac{|x|^{2k-1}}{2k-1} \to \infty$ so the series can't converge.

Answer (score 1):

$|x|>1$: Set $y +1:=|x|$, $y >0$.

$k \ge 1$:

$x^{2k-1}= (1+y)^{2k-1} \ge$

$1+ y(2k-1) \gt y(2k-1)$

$a_k = \frac{x^{2k-1}}{2k-1} \gt y >0.$

$\sum a_k$ is divergent.